# How to have folder and controller with same name in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC controller called Downloads. http://mysite/Downloads

I also want to put a physical file in a physical folder called http://mysite/Downloads/MyFile.zip.

If I simply create a folder, I get a 403 when browsing to http://mysite/Downloads.
(Most likely because of directory browsing is disabled)
But I want the MVC controller to kick in instead.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you browse to `http://mysite/Downloads/{ACTION}` it will fire your controllers action.

The only thing that won't work in your example is the `/Downloads` with no action. You could re-write this URL to redirect you to your default action.

In addition, you will need to have the routehandler ignore your download files. You can add a line in your global.asax file to ignore all zip files or some other ignore pattern that suits.

```
routes.Ignore("{resource}.zip");
```

Answer (score 5):

Since .NET 3.5, you can route existing files:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                          action = "Index", 
                          id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

So suppose we had a folder on the site root called `Markets` containing an  `audio.mp3` file:

```
\Markets
\Markets\audio.mp3
```

Assuming the existence of a `MarketsController`, if we made a request for `Markets`, it'd be routed to `Markets/Index`.

If we requested `/Markets/audio.mp3` we'd get the mp3 file and if we requested `Markets/AnythingElse`, normal routing would apply.