# ASP.NET Controller name conflicted with a folder name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting

In my ASP.NET MVC3 project, I have a folder called **Content** (the default folder for an MVC project). But I also have a controller called **Content**. And when I want to use the default actions of this controller, I simply use **http://domain/content/**, which is equivalent to **http://domain/content/index**. But IIS returns 403 error and thinks that I'm gonna get the directory list of the **Content Folder**. Well, this question is already discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437386/how-to-have-folder-and-controller-with-same-name-in-asp-net-mvc) question. But I don't know how to rewrite my URL to append the default action to it. May someone help please.

Comment: Just avoid using the same names, now you're getting into unnecessary problems that could be avoided other ways. Just rename you Content folder to public or something similar.

Comment: Well, I know that. But my question is a general case. What if you encounter a real name collision? Anyway, thank you for mentioning.

Answer (score 7):

You can get around this by changing routing configuration to specify:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

You will then need to set up some ignore rules to prevent genuine static content being gobbled up by the routing engine.

For example, I have a folder called Touch in  my app, and I also have a specific route for Touch. So the working config is:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.IgnoreRoute("Touch/Client/{*touchclientversion}", new { touchclientversion = @"(\d*)(/*)" });
```

I agree that this kind of thing should generally be avoided, but sometimes it's nice to have pretty URLs :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

In your case:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "DefaultContent",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Content", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: Downvote, because I said that I want to _rewrite_ the incoming URL before it maps to route rules. I already have those route rules in action. But IIS StaticHandler takes precedence in responding.

Comment: How about mentioning that in the post? Sorry, my mind scanner is not working today.