# route name same as a folder name

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-routing, asp.net-3.5

I am wondering if i can have a route like below.

```
    var newHandler = new CustomRouteHandler("~/folder_name/abc.aspx");
    routes.Add(new Route("folder_name", newHandler));
```

I have a folder in my asp.net website named "folder_name" and i want a route with same name to be added to route collection and routing it to abc.aspx in the same folder. I am not able to do this, i am getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Is there any way to have this "folder_name" routing to "~/folder_name/abc.aspx"?

Comment: please refactor your question so that it makes more sense.. your error is also pretty much self explanitory

Comment: yeah, error is self explanatory. I guess problem is if you want a custom route with same name as of your folder name code-behind then asp.net routing cannot route it to the page. Say i have a website mywebsite.com and there is a folder named "contact" in my asp.net website porject now i want mywebsite.com/contact routed to "~/contact/contactPage.aspx" but IIS tries to display contents of "contact" folder in this case and hence the error 403.14. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: its not the redirect and page is already created just want to add a user friendly route to it.

Comment: sounds like you need to double check your webserver settings..

Comment: See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437386/how-to-have-folder-and-controller-with-same-name-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i setup abc.aspx as default document for the "folder_name" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    routes.Add("folder_name", new Route("folder_name", new CustomRouteHandler("~/folder_name/abc.aspx")));
```