# Why does POST to /home return status 405 if root has folder named home

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-routing

I am looking for an explanation of certain behavior, and a way to possibly fix it.
This behavior exposes itself from a new project using the standard template for an ASP.NET MVC website and use the default IIS Express web server settings.

Make a post request against /home

In the root of the project create a folder named exactly "home"

Make a post request against /home

The second request will return a status of 405 Method Not Allowed.  This is the behavior I am trying to understand. It's creating unintended behavior problems while developers write features.  One developer makes a controller named logging.  Then weeks later someone adds a folder to namespace their code under Logging.  This now breaks all posts to the logging controller, and that is extremely hard to figure out, diagnose, and realize you even did it.

I thought it was the directory listing module/handler.  I set this to be IIS instead of IIS Express and started just deleting handlers and modules to get better behavior. Eventually the status code did change, but it didn't change to 200 it changed to 401. I haven't figured out where the 401 came from nor how to fix it.

How does the routing in this default scenario work and how can I get expected behavior?

Comment: [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437386/how-to-have-folder-and-controller-with-same-name-in-asp-net-mvc) might help with a possible solution

Comment: I looked through it and don't agree.  I am not looking to load files, I'm looking for it to not load files.  Also it states the issue might be not having a default action.  There is a default action, which is Index.  The RouteExistingFiles setting doesn't change the behavior one way or the other.  All our downloads are on external servers.

Comment: Yes I know, and its the first answer I was referring to - it mentions using `routes.Ignore` and _re-write this URL_. Of course you can always put all your 'other folders' under a 'master' folder with a name that does not match a controller (or perhaps App_Data)

Comment: I don't have a url I can ignore, because the url is the one I want to work.  Yes I know I can put the files under a different folder.  But this isn't something I can download into every employees brain 24/7.  The problem here is that is a crazy side affect.  Unless you know about this exact crazy behavior, creating new unused files isn't a safe change like it should be.  Absolutely dark code can bring down entire portions of the website. Without 100% end-to-end UI test coverage you'll eventually break something.  I'm looking for a pipeline behavior change so that development is safe.